# KDE windows change screen when screensaver appears / power savings starts

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, kde, screensaver

I have two monitors connected to my system, what I'd consider a primary and secondary display. I run a few applications on the second display.

The power saver will turn off the screens after some delay. When I reactivate the system (move mouse, touch key), the screens both come back on. However, the windows that were open on the second display are moved to the primary display.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Did you try to disable the power saving mode and let the screen saver do its thing normal ?

Comment: Is there even a screen saver in Kubuntu 18.04? There's certainly no options for one.

Comment: If it helps, I do not get the issue if I manually lock the screen and then unlock it again, so it's seems like a power saving rather than screensaver issue, but I am suffering the same problem - it gets annoying when I nip out of the office for 15 minutes and then I have to rearrange all my windows again when I get back!